# Record the size & position after drag & resize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I used jQuery UI [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) & [Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) to drag & resize a logo within a boundary.

How can I load the position & size of the resized & dragged logo from the parameter obtained by `.stop()` event callback in Resizable & Draggable API ?

**First Question:** I got `ui.position.left`, `ui.position.top`, `ui.size.width`, `ui.size.height` from the API, but how to load it back?

**Second Question:** How to capture the resultant ( dragged & resized ) contents within the red boundary to become a PNG / JPG using PHP ?

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/EVSZQ/4/).

Comment: what do you mean by `load it back` ?

Comment: load it back = display the dragged & resized image in correct position.

Comment: see my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049788/jquery-drag-n-drop-revert-back-to-original-position-not-working/19059085#19059085